# How can one pass two 3D tensors with only one common dimension (batch size) to a dynamic_lstm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to pass 2 tensors with different dimensions to a `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`. I am having difficulty because the dimensions do not match. I am open to suggestions for the best way to do this. These tensors are batches from a `tf.data.Dataset`

I have 2 tensors of shape:

tensor 1: (?, ?, 1024)

tensor 2: (?, ?, 128)

The first dimension is the batch size, the second dimension is the number of timesteps and the third dimension is the number of features to input at each timestep.

Currently, I have an issue that the number of timesteps for each dimension do not match. Not only that but they are inconsistent in size across samples (for some samples tensor 1 has 71 timesteps, sometimes it may have 74 or 77).

Is the best solution to dynamically pad the number of timesteps in the shorter tensor for each sample? If so, how would I do this?

Below is a code segment to show what I would like to do:

```
#Get the next batch from my tf.data.Dataset
video_id, label, rgb, audio = my_iter.get_next()

print (rgb.shape)    #(?, ?, 1024)
print (audio.shape)    #(?, ?, 128)

lstm_layer = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)

#This instruction throws an InvalidArgumentError, I have shown the output below this code
concatenated_features = tf.concat([rgb, audio], 2)
print (concatenated_features.shape)    #(?, ?, 1152)

outputs,_= tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_layer, concatenated_features, dtype="float32")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(num_epochs):
        sess.run(my_iter.initializer)
        for j in range(num_steps):
            my_outputs = sess.run(outputs)
```

The error upon calling `tf.concat` in a session:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [52,77,1024] vs. shape[1] = [52,101,128]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that I managed to find that may not be ideal but solves the problem unless someone has a better solution. Also, I am new to TensorFlow and open to edits if my reasoning is incorrect.

The problem is made more difficult by the fact that the tensors are stored in a `tf.data.Dataset` and any proposed `Dataset.map` function (used to perform element-wise operations) operates on symbolic tensors (that in this case do not have an exact shape). For this reason, I could not create a `Dataset.map` function using `tf.pad` but am open to solutions that do.

This solution uses the `Dataset.map` function and `tf.py_func` to wrap a python function as a TensorFlow operation. This function finds the difference between the 2 tensors (now `np.arrays` inside the function) and then uses `np.pad` to pad the timesteps dimension with 0's after the data.

```
def pad_timesteps(video, labs, rgb, audio):
""" Function to pad the timesteps of visual or audio features so that they are equal    
"""
    rgb_timesteps = rgb.shape[1] #Get the number of timesteps for rgb
    audio_timesteps = audio.shape[1] #Get the number of timesteps for audio

    if rgb_timesteps < audio_timesteps:
        difference = audio_timesteps - rgb_timesteps
        #How much you want to pad dimension 1, 2 and 3
        #Each padding tuple is the amount to pad before and after the data in that dimension
        np_padding = ((0, 0), (0,difference), (0,0))
        #This tuple contains the values that are to be used to pad the data
        padding_values = ((0,0), (0,0), (0,0))
        rgb = np.pad(rgb, np_padding, mode='constant', constant_values=padding_values)

    elif rgb_timesteps > audio_timesteps:
        difference = rgb_timesteps - audio_timesteps
        np_padding = ((0,0), (0,difference), (0,0))
        padding_values = ((0,0), (0,0), (0,0))
        audio = np.pad(audio, np_padding, mode='constant', constant_values=padding_values)

    return video, labs, rgb, audio

dataset = dataset.map(lambda video, label, rgb, audio: tuple(tf.py_func(pad_timesteps, [video, label, rgb, audio], [tf.string, tf.int64, tf.float32, tf.float32])))
```